# How do I fix "Environment error in Development"?

Tags: asp.net-core

All pages are routed correctly, but in the development environment I encounter this error:
[image]

The configuration method in the startup is as follows:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Main");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Main}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Share the error page

Comment: What error? There's literally nothing to this question.

Comment: Chris Pratt  : I put the error image in the text question

Comment: `All pages are routed correctly, but I only encounter this error when I enter the following page` To troubleshoot the issue, you can try 1) swap to Development environment or set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development  2) check event log of your server 3) check corresponding action/page handler code, or try to find useful info from application log

Answer (score 0):

problem solved
The error was due to the use and calling of a class on the user side (html view). When I deleted that class, the site ran easily and without error.